# Manipulating hash data for rChart - Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have some code that takes in a CSV file. I'm trying to use this information to create charts with [rChart](http://amardaxini.github.io/rchart/) in Ruby.

In my code I have CSV file loaded into a hash like the following:

```
CSV.new(open(url),:headers => true, :header_converters => :symbol, :converters => :all).each do |line|
    title = line.headers[0]
    points[line.fields[0]] = Hash[line.headers[1..-1].zip(line.fields[1..-1])]
end
```

Later...

```
points.keys.sort.each do |key|
    puts "---" # added for clarification in SO example of each key 
    points[key].each {|serie_name, point| puts "#{serie_name} = #{point}"}
    puts points[key].length # total number of series
end
```

Outputs:

```
---
wmt_oracle = 68
irt_oracle = 44
wmt_sql = 20
irt_sql = 11
operations = 4
5
---
wmt_oracle = 23
irt_oracle = 44
wmt_sql = 160
irt_sql = 8
operations = 3
5
---
wmt_oracle = 66
irt_oracle = 224
wmt_sql = 48
irt_sql = 15
operations = 3
5
```

In rChart datapoints for the stacked bar graph are added in the following way:

```
data.add_point([9,9,9,10,10,11,12,14,16,17,18,18,19,19,18,15,12,10,9],"Serie1");
data.add_point([10,11,11,12,12,13,14,15,17,19,22,24,23,23,22,20,18,16,14],"Serie2");
data.add_point([4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22],"Serie3");
. . .
```

For the above data I would need to have my data look like this:

```
data.add_point([68,23,66],"wmt_oracle");
data.add_point([44,44,224], "irt_oracle")
data.add_point([20,160,48], "wmt_sql")
data.add_point([11,8,15], "irt_sql")
data.add_point([4,3,3], "operations")
```

It would be in the format `data.add_point(array_of_points, serie_name)`

How can I get the data out of the hash into this format?

Comment: not clear! what you have and what you want,let us know. be specific.

Comment: I will try to fix it, but what is not clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
# Hash with default value []
transformed = Hash.new { |hash,key| hash[key] = [] } 
points.each { |k,v| v.each { |name,count| transformed[name] << count } }
```

Now `transformed` will be `{"wmt_oracle" => [68,23,66], "irt_oracle" => [44,44,224], ...}`

Then to add the points:

```
transformed.each { |name, values| data.add_point(values, name) }
```